# How could I pass in commands into a terminal that is already running in java (linux)

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command

I have been researching how to run a terminal command in java. I am doing this to make a program I can use to ssh into another pc (just as a project). How could I keep continuing putting commands in this terminal? If I run this I get a message to put in my password and if I do so it will print out what the messages the terminal spits out at the :
`while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line + "\n");

}`

line, but a few seconds after that my program will stop working.
I currently have a GUI that is just a button and if I press the button it will run this code. Could someone help me to fix the issue of it stopping and give me information on how I could continue to put commands into the terminal? Thanks.

```
    Process p = null;
    String[] command = {"/bin/sh",  "-c", "ssh 192.168.2.100"};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    String line = null;

    try {
        term = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line + "\n");    
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If I recall, when an error occurs it will block your program until you read it in.  That might be what's happening.

Comment: You should use a Java SSH library such as [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) or [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). This code is hugely error prone as you don't properly close streams and you don't read from the error stream. And you presumably do this all on the EDT.

Comment: I will have a look at that thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass the argument to live JVM, But there is way in which you can modify the some of the parameters which done using [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/), with this you can connect to live JVM  and send the parameters. which will be taken the effect immediately.

Hope that helps